# How do I get an error message returned to my stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am calling StoredProcA from StoredProcB like this:

```
EXEC StoredProcA(@a,@b,@c)
```

StoredProcA has code similar to this:

```
do some stuff...
if @a < @b
insert into TableX(ItemNo, ItemDescr, ItemCost)
values(@q, @r, @c)

if @@ERROR <> 0 begin
rollback transaction
raiserror('Insert into TableX failed', 16, 1)
return
end
do more stuff...
```

So when I call StoredProcA from StoredProcB how do I get that error message returned to StoredProcB and assign a variable to it?

Also, I cannot change StoredProcA in any way.

I assume it would be something like this:

```
declare @err_msg varchar(50)
EXEC @err_msg = StoredProcA(@a,@b,@c)
update MyTable Set Result = @err_msg Where Cost = @a
```

but I just can't figure out the exact syntax...

Comment: What do you mean assign a variable to the error? Also per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you should really be using `THROW` rather than `RAISERROR`.

Comment: This is a stored proc for an application that I am trying to do a mass update for.  So the code does not belong to me and I can't change it.  See my edit for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use T-SQL structured error handling to capture the error message text and reference with [ERROR_MESSAGE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql) in the catch block:

```sql
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC StoredProcA @a, @b, @c;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Result = ERROR_MESSAGE() WHERE Cost = @a;
    END CATCH;
```

Comment: This is great - I knew it was something simple.  Also you need END CATCH instead of just END

Comment: @HereBeBeer, Charlieface was kind enough to fix my copy\paste error. Please mark this as the answer to your question for better visibility to others with similar questions.